# Populate MultiChoice Spinner with Data from SQLite

Tags: android, spinner

I am developing an app that saves data into SQLite Database. I have an attribute which is in a multi-choice spinner.

[Multi Selection in Spinner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FZKAH.png)

[Selected items displayed in codes, separated by comma](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GSSdx.png)

I would like to save this to the database, but I don't know how to retrieve it so when I click it, it will show the items as selected in the spinner.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Btw, I got the MultiChoice Spinner library from here: http://v4all123.blogspot.com/2013/09/spinner-with-multiple-selection-in.html

EDIT:
Below is my code to manipulate MultiSelectionSpinner class:

```
package com.scbpfsdgis.femobilebetav20;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.guna.libmultispinner.MultiSelectionSpinner;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by William on 1/27/2018.
 */

public class FieldDetailActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MultiSelectionSpinner.OnMultipleItemsSelectedListener {

    Spinner spnMechMeth, spnTract;
    String limits = null;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_field_detail);

        String[] limits = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.limitations);
        List<String> limitList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(limits));

        MultiSelectionSpinner mssLimits = (MultiSelectionSpinner) findViewById(R.id.spnMainLim);
        mssLimits.setItems(limitList);
        mssLimits.setListener(this);

        spnMechMeth = findViewById(R.id.spnMechMeth);
        spnTract = findViewById(R.id.spnTract);

        System.out.println("Selected Strings: " + mssCanals.getSelectedItemsAsString());

    }

    @Override
    public void selectedIndices(List<Integer> indices) {

    }

    @Override
    public void selectedStrings(List<String> strings) {
        Toast.makeText(this, strings.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        System.out.println("Toast " + strings.toString());
    }
}
```

MultiSelectionSpinner.java:

```
package com.guna.libmultispinner;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.SpinnerAdapter;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

public class MultiSelectionSpinner extends Spinner implements
        OnMultiChoiceClickListener {

    public interface OnMultipleItemsSelectedListener{
        void selectedIndices(List<Integer> indices);
        void selectedStrings(List<String> strings);
    }
    private OnMultipleItemsSelectedListener listener;

    String[] _items = null;
    boolean[] mSelection = null;
    boolean[] mSelectionAtStart = null;
    String _itemsAtStart = null;
    ArrayAdapter<String> simple_adapter;
    String title = null;

    public MultiSelectionSpinner(Context context) {
        super(context);

        simple_adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(context,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        super.setAdapter(simple_adapter);
    }

    public MultiSelectionSpinner(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        simple_adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(context,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        super.setAdapter(simple_adapter);
    }

    public void setListener(OnMultipleItemsSelectedListener listener){
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which, boolean isChecked) {
        if (mSelection != null && which < mSelection.length) {
            mSelection[which] = isChecked;
            simple_adapter.clear();
            if (buildSelectedItemString().length() == 0) {
                simple_adapter.add("- Limitations -");
            } else {
                simple_adapter.add(buildSelectedItemString());
                System.out.println("Selected String: " + buildSelectedItemString().length());
            }
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "Argument 'which' is out of bounds.");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean performClick() {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
        builder.setTitle("Choose ...");
        builder.setMultiChoiceItems(_items, mSelection, this);
        _itemsAtStart = getSelectedItemsAsString();
        builder.setPositiveButton("Submit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                System.arraycopy(mSelection, 0, mSelectionAtStart, 0, mSelection.length);
                listener.selectedIndices(getSelectedIndices());
                listener.selectedStrings(getSelectedStrings());
            }
        });
        builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                simple_adapter.clear();
                if (_itemsAtStart.toString().trim().length() == 0) {
                    simple_adapter.add("- Limitations -");
                } else {
                    simple_adapter.add(_itemsAtStart);
                }
                System.arraycopy(mSelectionAtStart, 0, mSelection, 0, mSelectionAtStart.length);
            }
        });
        builder.show();
        return true;
    }

    public String getBuilderTitle(String att) {
        if (att.equalsIgnoreCase("L")) {
            return "Choose Limitations...";
        } else {
            return "Canals...";
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setAdapter(SpinnerAdapter adapter) {
        throw new RuntimeException(
                "setAdapter is not supported by MultiSelectSpinner.");
    }

    public void setItems(String[] items) {
        _items = items;
        mSelection = new boolean[_items.length];
        mSelectionAtStart = new boolean[_items.length];
        simple_adapter.clear();
        simple_adapter.add(_items[0]);
        Arrays.fill(mSelection, false);
        mSelection[0] = true;
        mSelectionAtStart[0] = true;
    }

    public void setItems(List<String> items) {
        _items = items.toArray(new String[items.size()]);
        mSelection = new boolean[_items.length];
        mSelectionAtStart  = new boolean[_items.length];
        simple_adapter.clear();
        simple_adapter.add(_items[0]);
        Arrays.fill(mSelection, false);
        mSelection[0] = false;
    }

    public void setSelection(String[] selection) {
        for (int i = 0; i < mSelection.length; i++) {
                mSelection[i] = false;
                mSelectionAtStart[i] = false;
        }
        for (String cell : selection) {
            for (int j = 0; j < _items.length; ++j) {
                if (_items[j].equals(cell)) {
                    mSelection[j] = true;
                    mSelectionAtStart[j] = true;
                }
            }
        }
        simple_adapter.clear();
        simple_adapter.add(buildSelectedItemString());
    }

    public void setSelection(List<String> selection) {
        for (int i = 0; i < mSelection.length; i++) {
            mSelection[i] = false;
            mSelectionAtStart[i] = false;
        }
        for (String sel : selection) {
            for (int j = 0; j < _items.length; ++j) {
                if (_items[j].equals(sel)) {
                    mSelection[j] = true;
                    mSelectionAtStart[j] = true;
                }
            }
        }
        simple_adapter.clear();
        simple_adapter.add(buildSelectedItemString());
    }

    public void setSelection(int index) {
        for (int i = 0; i < mSelection.length; i++) {
            mSelection[i] = false;
            mSelectionAtStart[i] = false;
        }
        if (index >= 0 && index < mSelection.length) {
            mSelection[index] = true;
            mSelectionAtStart[index] = true;
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Index " + index
                    + " is out of bounds.");
        }
        simple_adapter.clear();
        simple_adapter.add(buildSelectedItemString());
    }

    public void setSelection(int[] selectedIndices) {
        for (int i = 0; i < mSelection.length; i++) {
            mSelection[i] = false;
            mSelectionAtStart[i] = false;
        }
        for (int index : selectedIndices) {
            if (index >= 0 && index < mSelection.length) {
                mSelection[index] = true;
                mSelectionAtStart[index] = true;
            } else {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Index " + index
                        + " is out of bounds.");
            }
        }
        simple_adapter.clear();
        simple_adapter.add(buildSelectedItemString());
    }

    public List<String> getSelectedStrings() {
        List<String> selection = new LinkedList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < _items.length; ++i) {
            if (mSelection[i]) {
                //Edit: Get only limit code.
                selection.add(_items[i].substring(_items[i].indexOf("(")+1, _items[i].indexOf(")")));
            }
        }
        return selection;
    }

    public List<Integer> getSelectedIndices() {
        List<Integer> selection = new LinkedList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < _items.length; ++i) {
            if (mSelection[i]) {
                selection.add(i);
            }
        }
        return selection;
    }

    private String buildSelectedItemString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        boolean foundOne = false;

        for (int i = 0; i < _items.length; ++i) {
            if (mSelection[i]) {
                if (foundOne) {
                    sb.append(", ");
                }
                foundOne = true;
                //Edit: Get only limit code
                sb.append(_items[i].substring(_items[i].indexOf("(")+1, _items[i].indexOf(")")));
            }
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    public String getSelectedItemsAsString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        boolean foundOne = false;

        for (int i = 0; i < _items.length; ++i) {
            if (mSelection[i]) {
                if (foundOne) {
                    sb.append(", ");
                }
                foundOne = true;
                //Edit: Get only limit code
                sb.append(_items[i].substring(_items[i].indexOf("(")+1, _items[i].indexOf(")")));
            }
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you save selected items in database? In separate table? If yes, then before you populate the spinner, first fetch the items you selected from the table, and while populating the spinner compare each of the with the one from the table. If it is equal set as selected.
If you show us some code of your adapter or how you populate the spinner/ fetch data from database, basically I'm saying show us what have you tried.

Comment: I have added the code.

Comment: @arcticwhite, I haven't implemented the save yet.

Answer (score -1):

Use LoaderManager callbacks.
Take some help from here:

https://www.grokkingandroid.com/using-loaders-in-android/

Comment: Thank you, I'd give this a try. TBH, i am new to android and still exploring.